# Const operator in member function (Why can be in two different parts)?

Tags: c++, constants, member-functions, function-qualifier

We can find:

1)

```
const char *get() { return str; }
```

2)

```
int get() const { return A; }
```

What is the differences of "const" in this two different parts of the function?

Comment: The first one returns a pointer to const type, and the second is a const function.

Comment: char vs. int and pointer vs. non-pointer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first returns a pointer to a char which is constant - the value of str cannot be modified.  This is used to create an unchangable thing.

The second returns an int (from `A`) which doesn't modify the state of the class - hence can be called when the class is constant.

Comment: So in 1) there isn't any prommise of not to modify the parameter (str)?